# Eloquent: filter only rows which has related “children” rows

Tags: php, laravel

I want to filter only those categories which have at least one product. I write Category::with('products')->… but how do I filter out those empty categories? Those with no product?

**app\Category.php:**

```
class Category extends Model {

    // ...

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    // ...

}
```

**app\Http\Controller\CategoriesController.php:**

```
function getIndex() {
    $categories = Category::with('products')->get();
    return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution..

There’s an app function for that: has().

**app\Http\Controller\CategoriesController.php:**

```
function getIndex() {
    $categories = Category::with('products')->has('products')->get();
    return view('categories.index', compact('categories'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `has` in it

```
$users = Category::has('products')->get();
// only Categories that have at least one product are contained in the collection
```

`has()` is to filter the selecting model based on a relationship. So it acts very similarly to a normal WHERE condition. If you just use `has('relation')` that means you only want to get the models that have at least one related model in this relation.

Answer (score 1):

Us the `has` function

```
Category::with('products')->has('products')->get()
```